# Removing A Class from a Href Element with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a calendar that outputs today as a href tag like this:

```
<a class="ui-state-default ui-state-active" href="#">26</a>
```

All other days look like this:

```
<a class="ui-state-default" href="#">27</a>
```

When the page loads, I want to remove the *ui-state-active* class I do not wish for the day to be highlighted initially. This means all days should look like this after the page loads:

```
<a class="ui-state-default" href="#">26</a>
```

I've tried the following:

```
//WordPress Format
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    //Doesn't work
    $('.ui-state-default .ui-state-active').removeClass('ui-state-default ui-state-active').addClass('ui-state-default');
    //Tried to remove the default to see was that possible, didn't work
    $("ui-state-default").removeClass("ui-state-default");
    //Console log to know the script fired  
    console.log('fired');
});
```

But I have had no success.

Updated code based on comments:

```
//WordPress Format
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    //Doesn't work
    $('a').removeClass('ui-state-active');

    //Updates all links, except the calendar links
    $('a').addClass('colin');

    //Console log to know the script fired  
    console.log('fired');
});
```

Comment: Why not simply do `$('a').removeClass('ui-state-active')`?

Comment: This is part of WooCommerce and their WooBookings Plugin. I merely don't want the day highlight when the page loads. I belive it comes from datepicker.min.js

Comment: Or just override the style of the class so that it looks the way you want it (use `!important` on the property if needed)

Comment: Updated my code. I can't override the class as when a user selects a date, its ok to highlight it then. I just don't want it highlighted when the page loads.

Comment: I'll bet the `datepicker` widget is overwriting your change.  Might want to use the jquery-ui date picker api to get around this issue.  http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: Removing the class on document ready shouldn't affect any logic that adds the class later(?)

Comment: The datepicker will be generated when it is shown, so doing it on document.ready is too soon.  You need to hook into the datepicker api or set via options.

Comment: Just write a css rule that undoes what the active class does differently than the others. Or use `beforeShowDay` to add your own class and do what you want with css in that class

Answer (score 0):

You missed the dot in

```
$("ui-state-default").removeClass("ui-state-default");
```

it should be

```
$(".ui-state-default").removeClass("ui-state-default");
```

Comment: Maybe you should remove ui-state-active?

Comment: is the calendar refreshing using AJAX? if thats the case jQuery won't find the node with the class you are refreshing

Answer (score 0):

In this:

```
$('.ui-state-default .ui-state-active')
```

you shouldn't have a space between the classes. That means a descendant of `class="ui-state-default"` that has `class="ui-state-active"`. Since these classes are on the same element, not a parent and descendant, you should concatenate them.

```
$('.ui-state-default.ui-state-active')
```

If this doesn't work, the problem may be that the class isn't on the element when the page first loads. If this is in a jQuery UI Datepicker, the classes are added dynamically when you call `$(selector).datepicker()` or when the datepicker widget is opened. You probably need to do what you want in the appropriate callback options.